# Azure AD B2C Custom Policy REST API claims not being sent

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have the following Sign up/Sign in policy based on the [Custom Policy Starter Pack](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack) for Local Accounts.

I added the Technical Profile (REST-API-SignUp) step to the SignUpOrSignIn user journey. The API is called successfully, but the body of the request is empty. I am expecting the "email" claim to be present in the body of the request. I have tried with other claims and nothing seems to be sent in the request body.

**SignUpOrSignin.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<TrustFrameworkPolicy
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/online/cpim/schemas/2013/06"
  PolicySchemaVersion="0.3.0.0"
  TenantId="ukcustoms.onmicrosoft.com"
  PolicyId="B2C_1A_signup_signin"
  PublicPolicyUri="http://ukcustoms.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_signup_signin">

  <BasePolicy>
    <TenantId>ukcustoms.onmicrosoft.com</TenantId>
    <PolicyId>B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkExtensions</PolicyId>
  </BasePolicy>

  <RelyingParty>
    <DefaultUserJourney ReferenceId="SignUpOrSignIn" />
    <Endpoints>
      <Endpoint Id="Token" UserJourneyReferenceId="RedeemRefreshToken" />
    </Endpoints>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="PolicyProfile">
      <DisplayName>PolicyProfile</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" PartnerClaimType="sub"/>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="tenantId" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" DefaultValue="{Policy:TenantObjectId}" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_uid" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_tid" />

      </OutputClaims>
      <SubjectNamingInfo ClaimType="sub" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </RelyingParty>
</TrustFrameworkPolicy>
```

**TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml / ClaimsProviders** (truncated for brevity)

```xml
<ClaimsProvider>
  <DisplayName>Custom REST API</DisplayName>
    <TechnicalProfiles>
      <TechnicalProfile Id="REST-API-SignUp">
        <DisplayName>Validate user input and return TenantId and UserId.</DisplayName>
        <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.RestfulProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
        <Metadata>
          <Item Key="ServiceUrl">{{my service url}}</Item>
          <Item Key="AuthenticationType">Basic</Item>
          <Item Key="SendClaimsIn">Body</Item>
          <Item Key="DefaultUserMessageIfRequestFailed">Cannot process your request right now, please try again later.</Item>
          <Item Key="AllowInsecureAuthInProduction">true</Item>
        </Metadata>
        <CryptographicKeys>
          <Key Id="BasicAuthenticationUsername" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_RestClientId" />
          <Key Id="BasicAuthenticationPassword" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_RestClientPassword" />
         </CryptographicKeys>
        <InputClaims>
          <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
        </InputClaims>
        <OutputClaims>
          <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_uid" PartnerClaimType="extension_uid" />
          <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_tid" PartnerClaimType="extension_tid" />
        </OutputClaims>
      <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </TechnicalProfiles>
</ClaimsProvider>
```

**TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml / UserJourneys** (truncated for brevity)

```xml
<UserJourney Id="SignUpOrSignIn">
  <OrchestrationSteps>
    <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.signuporsignin">
      <ClaimsProviderSelections>
        <ClaimsProviderSelection ValidationClaimsExchangeId="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" />
      </ClaimsProviderSelections>
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>

    <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <Preconditions>
        <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
          <Value>objectId</Value>
          <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
        </Precondition>
      </Preconditions>
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>

    <!-- This step reads any user attributes that we may not have received when in the token. -->
    <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadWithObjectId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>

    <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="RESTGetUserClaims" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="REST-API-SignUp" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>

    <OrchestrationStep Order="5" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />

  </OrchestrationSteps>
  <ClientDefinition ReferenceId="DefaultWeb" />
</UserJourney>
```

Comment: I have a feeling that the issue I'm facing is due to caching on the Azure AD B2C server. I am investigating and will report.

Answer (score 1):

As suspected, this was an issue with caching on the Azure AD B2C server, where it wasn't serving the latest uploaded files.

This Microsoft YouTube video helped: https://youtu.be/eFcoRa79FqA

I would strongly recommend using Visual Studio Code and the Azure AD B2C extension.